# Magento 2 Can we split order with same order number

Tags: magento2.3, orders, shipping, sales-order, shipping-methods

Suppose, there are 2 types of products on my website **Product A** & **Product B**.
Here, are 3 cases -

> **Case 1** - When customer order **Product A**(any quantity) type product then from Magento we will get order number like this -
>   **0000001**
>
> **Case 2** - When customer order **Product B**(any quantity) type product then from Magento we will get order number like this -
>   **0000002**
>
> **Case 3** - When customers order both **Product A**(2 items) & **Product B**(3 items) in a single order, then we will get an order number like this - **0000003** - **it is fine**. But here we need to
>   split order number **0000003** into 2 orders internally (maybe like
>   this **0000003_1** & **0000003_2** or any other way), a customer must
>   have single order number but admin have 2 orders(**0000003_1** &
>   **0000003_2**) or any other way so that we can manage internally?

**Case 1** and **Case 2** is fine, we need to customize **Case 3**.

Comment: Yes, you can achive this by magento plugin concept.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya can you explain with code please

Answer (score 1):

**Case 3**: Please create one new order table for split orders and it will have a foreign key reference with the main order table. For e.g. let say **vendor_order** or **category_order**. So split order entries will be stored into that for your reference of split order related things like shipping method, payment method, totals, etc.

In admin panel, you can show the grid from this database table to show slitted orders.

Order split is a **multi-vendor marketplace concept** to split different vendor items to separate different shipping method for each vendor items and also to manage their payouts to the vendor.